# Probability that a length of pieces is more than a quarter

Tags: probability

Two points are chosen at random on a line of unit length.
What is the probability that each of the three pieces is of length greater than 0.25

I calculated it by assuming independence of $X$ and $Y$ and independence of $1-X-Y$,
where $X$ and $Y$ are the points chosen on the line.. I calculated $$P(X\gt 0.25)P(Y\gt 0.25)P(1-X-Y\gt 0.25)$$
Where I calculated the distribution of $X+Y$ as triangular distribution with
$f_U(u)=u$ for $0\le u\lt 1$
 And $f_U(u)=2-u$ for $1\le u\lt 2$.

Is it correct? If not please tell how to proceed?
And I got the answer as approximately $0.15$.

Comment: I am not sure if you can assume all three are independent, don't the lengths of segments $X$ and $Y$ determine the length of the last segment?

Comment: Hint:  do it geometrically.  Choosing two points on the interval is the same as choosing a single point on the square.  In this case, you'll find it more convenient to assume that $y>x$, say, so you only have points in the square above the diagonal (double the probability to get a valid distribution).  Now you add the condition that $x>\frac 14$.  then you want $y-x>\frac 14$, and $1-y>\frac 14$  the answer is twice the area of the region defined by all these constraints.

Comment: No, they are not independent. You might want to look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663639/do-the-lengths-of-all-three-segments-necessarily-have-the-same-distribution). You can use it to calculate what you want.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/aG1L4y8.png